# About ![CDATA[, what is it?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, smarty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the meaning of CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339702/what-is-the-meaning-of-cdata)

What is, and when is used the ![CDATA[ string/variable/constant? (I don't know what is it)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a way to escape large sections of text in XML documents.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML):

> In an XML document or external parsed entity, a CDATA section is a section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret as only character data, not markup.

By the way, it is `<![CDATA[]]>`, not `![CDATA[]]`.

Answer (score 2):

The term CDATA ((Unparsed) Character Data) is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser.

Some text, like JavaScript code, contains a lot of "<" or "&" characters. To avoid errors script code can be defined as CDATA.

[Ref](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Answer (score 2):

CDATA is used in XML (and hence XHTML) to insert text which might include "special" characters (eg. < and >) which would normally break the XML parser (and to be fair, confuse a human reader, as well!).

For example, you could use it to embed a code segment inside an XML document.

Answer (score -1):

It is used in XML, inside can be everything.