# Why do we need to use //<![CDATA[ in an @using statement?

Tags: cdata

In the following block, why do we need the `//<![CDATA[     ...      //]]>` block?

```
@using(Script.Foot()) {
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        alert('page loaded');
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
}
```

**Related Questions:**

[What is the meaning of CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339702/what-is-the-meaning-of-cdata)

Answer (score 0):

- **Why `CDATA` sections?** CDATA sections tell the XML parser to read the characters without interpreting them as element or entity markup.
- **Why leading `//` marks?** We introduce the CDATA opening and closing tags with `//` marks, so the JavaScript parser ignores the CDATA tags.
- **Why .cshtml but not .html?** The .cshtml pages, which ASP.NET MVC uses, are XML based whereas .html pages are not.

**References**

[CData Sections (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[What is the meaning of CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339702/what-is-the-meaning-of-cdata)